# Gather keys from multi level Hashmaps to an Ordered ListBuffer in Scala

Tags: scala, hashmap, listbuffer

I have a `Hashmap` say H1, with the following components :

H1:
Key1: `Int` 
Value1: `Hashmap H2`

H2: 
Key2: `Int` 
Value2 : Objects of multiple types

My target is to gather all `keys` of H2s in H1 in an ordered `Listbuffer` (distinct values) the fastest way possible.

Example :

```
(35->((3->obj1),(4->obj2)), 
36->((4->obj3),(6->obj4)), 
37->((5->obj5),(3->obj6)))
```

I would have a `ListBuffer(3,4,5,6)` and H1 might grow relatively big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
h1Map
  .valuesIterator
  .flatMap(_.keysIterator)
  .distinct
  .toList
  .sorted
```

If you really need a *mutable* **ListBuffer** you can change the `toList` with `to[ListBuffer]` *(if you are in `2.12-`)* or `to(ListBuffer)` *(if you are in `2.13+`)*.
However, I would recommend you to try to avoid *mutable* collections and stick with *immutable* ones.

Comment: Thank you, it did work out. I am adding a feature to pre-existing algorithm and ListBuffer is used in most structures and methods inputs, I did not want to go for all the restructuring. The resut is actually an input for a pre-existing method widely used.